# Is the mechanism used in Passwordless module widely used?

Tags: authentication, passwords

I came across [Passwordless](https://passwordless.net/) which uses email/SMS to allow the user to login. Is this mechanism widely used? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using such mechanism? I'm asking because I haven't seen any applications that use the mechanism.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "widely used". Google and Facebook use it, does that count?

Comment: @JörgWMittag but Google doesn't use the email/SMS only right? It's password AND SMS. Don't know about Facebook tough. I don't use it.

Comment: For most scenarios, "avoid misusing passwords by relying on your email provider to authenticate you via the POP protocol" is worse than "avoid misusing passwords by relying on an OAUTH provider to authenticate you via the OAUTH protocol". So, I recommend OAUTH over Passwordless.  As a two-factor authentication, Passwordless is reasonable.  As a login substitute, I'm not a fan.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*The original answer was based on a wrong assumption, since I haven't followed the link provided in the question. I edited the answer now, but kept the original version at the bottom, since it may be helpful.*</sup>

Talking about the wide usage, I would assert that a similar system exists in nearly every website under a form “I forgot my password”. Using Passwordless is like clicking on “I forgot my password” every time you want to logon: you'll receive a link with a temporary password, and you'll be able to use this password only once or during a short time.

### Drawbacks

Passwordless claims to solve the problem of bad, easy to bruteforce passwords, but the question which should be asked is why so many persons are using those bad passwords in the first place?

Because good passwords are not user friendly.

Those are two bad passwords:

```
nancy
5/8/1987  (that would be someone's birthday date)
```

Those are two [good](https://xkcd.com/936/) passwords:

```
$.HKk_ey",0>Jo^Y:m~2d
Correct horse battery staple!
```

Which ones are (1) easy to remember, (2) fast to type on a 4.7 inch tactile screen on a subway and (3) not error prone? Thus, `nancy` is appealing for users, while `$.HKk_ey",0>Jo^Y:m~2d` is not.

Passwordless has the very same constraint of user unfriendliness (or maybe even user hatred). Instead of typing the name of a website in Google, typing your bruteforce-welcoming credentials and start using the app, you should now:

1. Start your e-mail client,
2. Wait for an e-mail to arrive, which would take a while since you're on a morning commute subway train with a connection which drops every fifteen seconds,
3. Wait a few more minutes, asking yourself where's this e-mail,
4. Notice that you made a typo in your e-mail address on the website,
5. Enter the right address,
6. Repeat the previous steps,
7. Wonder why there is still nothing in your inbox,
8. Notice that the e-mail was delivered to spam,
9. Discover that the e-mail client blocks links of spam e-mails,
10. Mark it as not spam,
11. Switch to the inbox,
12. Open the e-mail,
13. Click on the link.

The user experience could be even more terrible with SMS. If I'm visiting a website on a device other than a smartphone, should I copy the code by hand? Passwordless seem to claim that they use GUIDs, which are all but user friendly when it comes to typing them.

So let's review the claims on the home page:

- **Faster to deploy**: no idea. Personally, I use OAuth. It's terribly straightforward to implement in most mainstream languages thanks to the existent libraries. And developers who would decide to store credentials in the app database are doing it wrong anyway.
- **Better for your users**: as explained above, Passwordless is terrible for your users.
- **Better security**: I don't see how Passwordless would protect your users against phishing or man in the middle attacks. Even worse, their “passwords” are GUIDs, which, in many languages, are generated without using a pseudo-random **cryptographically secure** number generator. In layman terms, this means that with enough effort, anyone can find the passwords of your users, making the system not only useless, but actively harmful.

  Indeed, they could have been generating actual cryptographically secure passwords instead, which would make it actually secure. The application can probably be modified very easily for that.
- **Flexible**: maybe.

### Benefits

After discussing the major issues which prevents this system from being widely used, there are two benefits which should be mentioned: the fact that the user cannot forget a password and the fact that the same password won't be reused for other websites.

The first benefit is mostly irrelevant for the users of Google Chrome or other browsers which do a great job of remembering passwords. Since Google Chrome synchronizes this information to all devices, users don't have to remember passwords at all, until a disaster erases all their Chrome preferences. In all cases, any capable website would have a “I forgot my password”, which is what Passwordless actually is.

The second benefit is indeed valuable and there are no many user-friendly alternatives.

---

### Original answer

A more widely known form is **two-factor authentication**. The user still requires to enter a password, but also a code sent by SMS.

This technique ensures that if somebody peeks over your shoulder¹ when you enter a password, the person still can't access your account later. The only way for the person to access your account is to also be able to access to your mobile device or track the SMS you receive. This technique is, for example, [used by Google](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/).

Similarly, TOTP can be used to generate one-time passwords on the fly on user's device without the need to use SMS or other communication mechanisms. For example, [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/) uses [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) to provide this additional mechanism.

In both cases, while there is a benefit, it is still possible to hack an account which uses two-factor authentication. For instance, imagine a hacker wants to get access to a few Google accounts of random persons. He creates (or hacks) a popular gaming/streaming/download-paid-apps-for-free/porn/whatever website which asks new users to enter a password when registering. Once the password is entered, the website attempts to authenticate to Google. If that works, Google sends an SMS, while, at the same time, the malicious website tells the user that he should be receiving an SMS with a code which should be entered to confirm the registration. A clueless user may not notice that the SMS is sent by Google, and provide the code to the hacker's website. As soon as it happens, the hacker has access to Google account of the user.

---

<sup>¹ In most cases, this would rather be a keylogger or the man in the middle.</sup>

Comment: The mentioned library sends a link to the email account where the user can click to go to the website. I think that would prevent the attack you mention since they won't be manually entering the code